# C++ Merge sorting error breaks on newline text

Tags: c++, vector, mergesort

I am doing a merge sort with a vector of strings. So far I implemented most of the algorithm in the function.

I take input from the command prompt using < input.txt to pass input to stdin from a text file , and then output using >output.txt.

The text file would look like this (notice the blank line):

> Hello 
>   world.
>
> 3 days of summer!

For each line of text, it is inserted into a vector , that text is then rotated left and pushed back into the vector, and repeats until n-1. And then I run the merge sort to sort the vector strings and print the output.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    string input;
    while(getline(cin, input)){

        vector<string> v;
        //Shift string to the left by 1 character and add it to the vector
        for(int i=0; i< input.length(); i++)
        {
            v.push_back(input);
            rotate(input.begin(),input.begin()+1,input.end());
        }


        //  Print original vector
        cout << "******original*******"<< endl;
        for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        {
            cout << v[i] << endl;
        }


        //Do the mergesort
        mergeSort(v, 0, v.size() - 1);

        //print output
        cout << "*****sorted******"<< endl;
        for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        {
            cout << v[i] << endl;
        }

    } //end while loop
}
```

```cpp
void mergeSort(vector<string> &a, int from, int to)
{
    if (from == to)
    {
        return;
    }
    int mid = (from + to) / 2;

    mergeSort(a, from, mid);
    mergeSort(a, mid + 1, to);
    merge(a, from, mid, to);
} 

void merge(vector<string> &a, int from, int mid, int to)
{
    int n = to - from + 1; 
    vector<string> b(n); 
    int i1 = from; 
    int i2 = mid + 1;
    int j = 0; /

    while (i1 <= mid && i2 <= to)
    {
        if (a[i1].compare(a[i2]) < 0)
        {
            b[j] = a[i1];
            i1++;
        }
        else
        {
            b[j] = a[i2];
            i2++;
        }
        j++;
    }

    while (i1 <= mid)
    {
        b[j] = a[i1];
        i1++;
        j++;
    }

    while (i2 <= to)
    {
        b[j] = a[i2];
        i2++;
        j++;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        a[from + j] = b[j];
    }
}
```

My expected output should be:

```
******original*******
Hello
elloH
lloHe
loHel
oHell
******sorted*******
Hello
elloH
lloHe
loHel
oHell
******original*******
world.
orld.w
rld.wo
ld.wor
d.worl
.world
******sorted*******
.world
d.worl
ld.wor
orld.w
rld.wo
world.
******original*******
******sorted*******
******original*******
3 days of summer!
 days of summer!3
days of summer!3
ays of summer!3 d
ys of summer!3 da
s of summer!3 day
 of summer!3 days
of summer!3 days
f summer!3 days o
 summer!3 days of
summer!3 days of
ummer!3 days of s
mmer!3 days of su
mer!3 days of sum
er!3 days of summ
r!3 days of summe
!3 days of summer
******sorted*******
 days of summer!3
 of summer!3 days
 summer!3 days of
!3 days of summer
3 days of summer!
ays of summer!3 d
days of summer!3
er!3 days of summ
f summer!3 days o
mer!3 days of sum
mmer!3 days of su
of summer!3 days
r!3 days of summe
s of summer!3 day
summer!3 days of
ummer!3 days of s
ys of summer!3 da
```

The problem is, when there is a blank newline in the text file then the sorting stops. This is the output I get:

```
******original******* 
Hello 
elloH 
lloHe 
loHel 
oHell
******sorted******* 
Hello 
elloH 
lloHe 
loHel 
oHell
******original******* 
world. 
orld.w 
rld.wo 
ld.wor 
d.worl 
.world
******sorted******* 
.world 
d.worl 
ld.wor 
orld.w 
rld.wo 
world.
******original*******
```

What seems to be wrong?

Comment: Please provide a full reproducible code, that can be copied and compiled.

Answer (score 1):

When your vector is empty the `v.size() - 1` you pass to `mergeSort` becomes a large positive number (`size_t` returned from `v.size()` is unsigned). This is then cast to an `int` which probably results in `-1`. This will eventually result in somewhere inside `merge` accessing out of the bounds of the vector. As `to` is less than `from` you are also likely to end up with infinite recursion.

The simplest fix is to not sort when your vector has less than 2 elements:

```
if ( v.size >= 2 )
{
  mergeSort(v, 0, v.size() - 1);
}
```